# appium server not launching on windows

Tags: appium

Downloaded AppiumForWindows-1.1.0.0 for windows.On clicking appium.exe,appium server is not launching on windows8 platform.

Please help me regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

AppiumforWindows works fine for me. But try to execute it from command line like this:

appium --app